# Sorting a 2d array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a 2d array with four columns (lettered *A*--*D*) and each column has three rows. Here is a visual representation of my array:

```
A  B  C  D  
1  3  9  0
2  8  2  1
8  4  10 3
```

I want to sort the columns by the smallest number in each column. This is how I want my array to look after sorting:

```
D  A  C  B
0  1  9  3
1  2  2  8
3  8  10 4
```

The *D* column is first because the smallest number in the column is `0`, and `0` is the smallest among all columns' smallest numbers. *A* is next because the smallest number in *A* is `1`, and `1` is smaller than `2` (the smallest number in column *C*) and `3` (the smallest number in column *B*).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: How does your 2d array look like in real implementation? Are the columns (cells) nested within rows, or vice versa? Your wording sounds like the latter, but I almost always see the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that will do:

```
arr = [[1,2,8], [3,8,4], [9,2,10], [0,1,3]]
arr.sort! { |a, b| a.min <=> b.min }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input = %q(1  3  9  0
2  8  2  1
8  4  10 3)

array = input.split("\n").map(&:split).transpose

result = array.map{|x| x.map(&:to_i).sort}.sort
#=> [[0, 1, 3], [1, 2, 8], [2, 9, 10], [3, 4, 8]]
```

Comment: May I ask why it was downvoted when it works correctly with the information provided in the problem?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the way you built the input array is unnecessary.

Comment: Just to help OP, as he did not mention how 2d array was created.

Comment: The OP said "here is a visual representation of my array", so we can assume he had a regular Ruby array, and he was trying to be helpful to us. Your assumption that he started with text is most likely incorrect.

Comment: You're not asking why it was downvoted when it doesn't work correctly?